# SailsJS find models by radius geolocation

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Im using sails v0.12 with postgres (cube and earthdistance extensions)

i have a model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    lat: {
      type: 'float'
    },
    lng: {
      type: 'float'
    },
    private: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
    title: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  }

};
```

I need to find all models around the user (for example in a 100 meter radius)

How would i do this?

Comment: Do your libraries help out with this, or are you wanting to do this with plain old math?

Comment: In either case, a good strategy might be to query for all users with in a square around your target (so with lat and lng in given ranges), then further filter your results to those within the circle in code.

Comment: Found something similer, I have not tested it myself but can help
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77072/return-all-results-within-a-30km-radius-of-a-specific-lat-long-point

Comment: @Sandeep thanks but i dont need a way to do it with custom queries i need to do it using the sails blueprint

Comment: Probably a late reply but https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/ Can this help?